# Catalina Update: Calendar Crashes When Trying to Print, CalDAV Problems With Confluence Calendar Integration

Tags: macos, calendar, confluence, macos-catalina, caldav

After a macOS Catalina update the calendar app crashes when I try to print the week overview. Also the integration of confluence calendars via calDAV has problems with the UI. The text of the calDAV entries only shows up when I modify the color. After some time calendar forgets this new setting and the text is gone again. Both problems appeared directly after the Catalina update.

Crash report:

```
Crashing on exception: cannot set button color to nil
```

If I remove the Confluence CALDAV account, printing works fine.

Comment: Have you tried with a fresh macOS and Confluence profile? Are there any logs?

Comment: @dirdi: I dropped the old confluence caldav account and created a new one. Same problem. For the logs: Where could I check logs of the calendar application?